# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am testing my chrome extension and it is failing to load a local jquery-3.3.1.js, even I tried online jquery URL https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js 
 it gave the same error over and over again what should i do to make it work, my code looks like this

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Spoiler Blocker</title>
            <link href="popup.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="form">
                <h3>Type in the name of a show you want to Unspoil</h3>
                <input id="spoiler-input" type="text" placeholder="Breaking Bad">
                <button id="unspoil-button" class="btn btn-primary">Unspoil</button>
            </div>
    
            <main id="showslist" class="app__body">
                    <!-- TaskItems will be rendered here -->
            </main>
    <!--         <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.3.0.js"></script>
     -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js "></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./init.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./popup.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./content.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm if init.js, popup.js are found by the plugin?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Yes both files are found

Answer (score -1):

try removing the blank character at the end of the string :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
```